# Use jQuery to select text not in an element

Tags: jquery

Say i have this:

```
<div class='myDiv'>
    <p>hello</p>
    hello
    <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

How does one grab the text hello between the two P tags using jQuery?

Comment: Everything has (or can have) a parent element, can you show the rest of the dom?

Comment: If you give more context (read: the code surrounding the snippet you posted), it'd be fairly easy to do. Or is this the entire document?

Comment: Ok, edited it slightly to give more context

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$('.myDiv')
  .contents()
  .filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
  }).text();
```

[How do I select text nodes with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery/298758#298758)

http://jsfiddle.net/6us8r/

Comment: Not every browser works the same way with text nodes, not sure if this solution circumvents that problem...

Comment: @Phil See the comments and solutions at the link posted above.

Answer (score 0):

js1568 has a better approach

$('div.myDiv').filter('p').text() would probably work.

I take it back, filter would not work. maybe something like:

```
var jText = $('div.myDiv').clone();
jText.find('p').remove();
jText.text();
```