# How to remove text (without removing inner elements) from a parent element using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Imagine that I have something like the following (modified from http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-get-text-element-without-child-element/)

```
<div id="foo">
    first
    <div id="bar1">
        jumps over a lazy dog!
    </div>
    second
    <div id="bar2">
        another jumps over a lazy dog!
    </div>
    third
</div>
```

How can I remove just (only text) "first", "second" and "third" from DOM without affecting any of the child elements.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715167/jquery-how-to-remove-the-text-but-not-the-children-elements
or
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags

Comment: it's answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388507/use-jquery-to-select-text-not-in-an-element

Comment: The answers in all of the linked questions are all either completely wrong, cause unwanted issues such as lost event handlers, or break in certain browsers (e.g. use of `nodeType` constants).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you want to remove all child text nodes you can use [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) and then [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to reduce the matched set to only text nodes:

```
$("#foo").contents().filter(function () {
     return this.nodeType === 3; 
}).remove();​​​​​​​
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/UK9xU/).

**Note**: This will preserve any existing event handlers on the child elements, which answers using `.html()` will not do (since the elements are removed from the DOM and added back in).

**Note 2**: Answers in some of the linked questions show similar code to that in my answer here, but they use the `nodeType` constants (e.g. `return this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE`). This is bad practice since IE below version 9 does not implement the `Node` property. It's safer to use the integers (which can be found in the [DOM level 2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1950641247)).

Comment: The terrible `.html` solutions don't remove handlers in this case (or maybe they do?), but that's just by accident because `.html` can insert nodes too (undocumented, though). Edit: Ok they definitely do remove handlers because of the implicit `.empty()` in `.html`

Comment: @Esailija - Using the code from mgraph's answer seems to remove the event handler: http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/PXxC4/1/

Comment: so what does the 3 actually refer to? looking over the Dom level 2 spec i don't see nodetypes listed in any way by numbers. and i'm curious :)

Comment: @JamieHutber - They are listed with numbers. See [this section](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1950641247). Looks like my link got messed up so it links to some random other part of the doc.

Comment: argh brilliant, thanks. Ye this is very interesting way of handling elements. I'll certainly be looking at ways i can use this. Cheers

Comment: If you get an ILLEGAL error in your browser(esp. WebKit) then look at the accepted answer to this question for your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404526/unexpected-token-illegal-in-webkit

Answer (score 13):

Here's a non-jQuery version which works in all major browsers back to IE 5, just to demonstrate how unscary life without jQuery is.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/aHW9J/

Code:

```
var el = document.getElementById("foo"), child = el.firstChild, nextChild;

while (child) {
    nextChild = child.nextSibling;
    if (child.nodeType == 3) {
        el.removeChild(child);
    }
    child = nextChild;
}
```

Comment: @JamieHutber: Don't worry, it'll all be OK.

Answer (score 7):

try this :

```
$("#foo").html($("#foo").find("div"));​
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/PXxC4/

Answer (score 4):

You could use this.

```
$("#foo").html($("#foo").children());​
```