# Remove text within element leaving child element alone

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a paragraph tag with some text and an anchor within it. How would I remove just the text and not the anchor link? I've looked into .innerHTML, but I can't mess with the anchor link because it's href value is dynamically generated.

```
<p>Text to be removed <a href="blahrdyblahr">Link Text</a></p>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove text (without removing inner elements) from a parent element using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633610/how-to-remove-text-without-removing-inner-elements-from-a-parent-element-using)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`children()` returns all direct descendants of the element that are not text nodes.

```js
$('p').html(function(){
  return $(this).children();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Text to be removed <a href="blahrdyblahr">Link Text</a></p>
<p><a href="blahrdyblahr">Link Text</a> Text to be removed</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the text from the textNode itself (which is the first child).

```js
document.querySelector('p').firstChild.textContent = '';
```

```html
<p>Text to be removed <a href="blahrdyblahr">Link Text</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to give another option (and try to release myself from the guilt of misunderstanding the question)

```
$('p').contents().not($('p').children()).remove()
```

This will remove text and comment nodes.

`.contents()` returns al the children including text and comment nodes, so we used the `.not()` function to exclude the `.children()` since children won't contain the text node, leaving only the text and comment nodes to be removed.

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aL7cmmjd/

See here: https://api.jquery.com/contents/

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over tag's children and remove text nodes:

```js
const container = document.querySelector('p');

for (let i = 0; i < container.childNodes.length; ++i) {
  if (container.childNodes[i].nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    container.removeChild(container.childNodes[i]);
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Text to be removed <a href="blahrdyblahr">Link Text</a></p>
```