# jQuery: Remove string that has no parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a document that I can't edit in PHP looking like this:

```
<div class="car-search-field-div">
  <label class="simple_hide">Türen</label>
     <div class="myClear"></div>

     doors_count

     <input id="car-search-form-field-doors_count" name="search[doors_count]" type="text" value="" placeholder="Anzahl Türen ab">
 </div>
```

Now I am trying to remove the string "doors_count" via jQuery but can't adress it properly. When I try something like:

```
$('.car-search-field-div').remove('iventory_number', '');
```

The placeholder of the input field gets removed, but the string "doors_number" still is there. I also thought of using the xpath of the string, but that doesn't work either.

Is there a way to adress / remove a string that has no element wrapped around it? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: `doors_count` has element `<div class="car-search-field-div">` as wrapper. To clear text use `$('.car-search-field-div').text('')`, to clear html too use `$('.car-search-field-div').html('')`

Comment: Use the [DOM API](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) directly. Here, for example: `document.querySelectorAll("input[name^='search']").forEach(({ previousSibling }) => previousSibling.remove())`.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove inside all text inside `.car-search-field-div`

```
$('.car-search-field-div').contents().filter(function () {
     return this.nodeType === 3; 
}).remove();
```

more detail [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633610/how-to-remove-text-without-removing-inner-elements-from-a-parent-element-using)

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/meL9d6a5/)

Comment: Thank you very much! This did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You need DOM access

```js
document.querySelector(".car-search-field-div").childNodes.forEach(node => {
  if (node.nodeType === 3 && node.textContent.trim() === "doors_count") node.remove()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="car-search-field-div">
  <label class="simple_hide">Türen</label>
  <div class="myClear"></div>
  doors_count
  <input id="car-search-form-field-doors_count" name="search[doors_count]" type="text" value="" placeholder="Anzahl Türen ab">
</div>
```